Bedeutung von "Signatur" im Kontext eines akademischen Journals oder einer Bibliothek
Ich bin auf den Begriff „Signatur“ in diesem Dokument gestoßen. Deutet es die Gesamtzahl von Autoren in der jeweiligen Publikation an?

Vote to close weil die Frage mit einem Wörterbuch https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Signatur beantwortet werden kann (auch wenn die Tatsache, dass die Signatur hier nur eine Zahl ist, irreführend sein kann).

@Raketenolli It's about the meaning in context. The conventional sense of "a certification of authenticity" does not apply.

Ah okay. I see what you mean. I did not use Duden. Thank you.

Die englische Überschrift und die auf deutsch gestellte Frage passen nicht zusammen und haben zu zwei Antworten in unterschiedlichen Sprachen geführt. Ich habe die Überschrift mal übersetzt und ergänzt.

It's entry #2 in the DWDS's word description: a sequence of numbers (and possibly letters) indicating where it is found in a library.

Die "Signatur" in Bibliothekskatalogen ist das auf dem Buchrücken abgedruckte Label, auf das man beim Durchgehen der Regale gucken kann, um schnell ein Buch zu finden. Es sollte (wie eine Unterschrift) möglichst eindeutig sein, damit man die Bücher nicht herausnehmen muß, um ein individuelles Buch zu finden.
